# iPhone TableView alternative options for Check Mark Accessory

Tags: uitableview

I'm looking for the best approach to this problem.

In my tableview I have a list of options from which you can select one and only one.  The problem is the selection to choose is not obvious without displaying more details on the option.

If I use the disclosure indicator or button for the more detail, I lose the checkmark functionality.

In searching around I see some have used the cell Image as a work around.
I see others instead of using the standard disclosure button have created custom disclosure button looking like a checkmark.  Haven't seen this one but is it viable (HIG) to add a button in the cell ('more info') to launch the next tableview.

My thought was to use a disclosure indicator and on the second view in the navigation bar (where the edit button usually is) add a 'selectMe' button.

I think I am probably manage to code either of the above, am just asking for information on what is the best (HIG) way.

Example

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3 (x)
Option 4

Where x is the checked one

But in order to know which is the best choice you need to see

Option 3 (Header)

Option 3-a
Option 3-b
Option 3-c >
Option 3-d

Where even at this level option 3-c might have additional information.

Any guidance you can provide would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch? All can be off by default, and the user can switch on the one he likes so far. Go into detail view to read more and come back and the switch option will be saved.